# laravel- Set default date as tomorrow

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am using bootstrap date picker and I want tomorrow's day as default date in the date picker. Or I don't want to select today's date.

Here is my html code.

```
<input name = "{{$prefix}}valid_to" type="text" class = "form-control datepicker valid_to" placeholder = "Valid To" data-date-start-date="d" value = "{{date('Y-m-d')}}">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using..

```
<input name = "{{$prefix}}valid_to" type="text" class = "form-control datepicker valid_to" placeholder = "Valid To" data-date-start-date="d" value = "{{date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'))}}">
```

Answer (score 4):

Or use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub)

```
value = "{{ Carbon\Carbon::now()->addDay()->format('Y-m-d') }};
```

Comment: Carbon IS the DateTime class

Answer (score 3):

Try using `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'))` instead of `date('Y-m-d')`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the DateTime class:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1 day');
```

and then in your view,

`echo $date->format('Y-m-d');`